# Linker Error in c++, It is just a simple class program, I am beginner at c++

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include"header_complex.h"

using namespace std;




class Complex
{
private:
 float real,imag;
public:
 Complex(); //default cnstructor
 Complex(float, float); //parametrize constructor
 void set_real(float);
 void set_imag(float);
 float get_real();
 float get_imag();
 void input();
 void display();

};


int main()
{
 Complex c1;  // object creation

 c1.display();
 c1.input();
 c1.display();

 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


//Functions definations

Complex::Complex(float a=0, float b=0)
{
  real = a;
  imag = b;
}

 void Complex::set_real(float a)
{
  a = real;
}

void Complex::set_imag(float a)
{
  a = imag;
}

float Complex::get_real()
{
  return real;
}
float Complex::get_imag()
{
  return imag;
}

void Complex::input(){
  cout << "Enter Real part ";
  cin >> real;
  cout << "Enter Imaginary part " ;
  cin >> imag;
}

void Complex::display()
{
  cout << "Real part is  " << real;
  cout << "Imaginary part is  " << imag;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code, thanks.

Comment: Please format your source code using { } button.

Comment: Ok, but what's the issue ? Any errors ? What doesn't work - don't be afraid to include details.

Comment: A linker error means you probably didn't supply some library when **linking** your code. How do you compile & link this program?

Comment: What's the linker error?

Comment: You are missing implementation to your default constructor, the way you have done it, is ambigious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol "public: __thiscall
>   Complex::Complex(void)"
>   (??0Complex@@QAE@XZ) referenced in
>   function _main

Reading and understanding the error message is a very important skill to learn to get ahead.  "Unresolved external" is an error message that the linker produces when it sees you using an identifier but cannot find a definition for it in any of the supplied .obj and .lib files.

Complex::Complex(void) is the missing identifier.  It is the constructor of the Complex class that doesn't take any arguments.  You declared it, you use it, you just didn't write the code for it.

You can get help on a linker or compiler error by selecting the error message in the Error List window and pressing F1.

Comment: But what i did merge the two constructor is legal some people says this.

Comment: You can merge them, but if you do, you should not declare `Complex();` in the class definition.  Only declare `Complex(float,float);` and provide default values for the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why anyone would describe an error message so vaguely (say, as a "linker error") without copying and pasting the error message. That said, I was able to compile and link your program on Linux by making the following changes:

1) I moved the class definition for Complex into a header file named `header_complex.h`, since that's what the main program `#include`s.

2) I added a definition for the default constructor:

```
Complex::Complex() : real(0), imag(0) {}
```

3) I added `-lstdc++` to the command line:

```
gcc complex.cpp -lstdc++
```

By the way, I think you're going to want to modify your display method to add some `endl`s:

```
  cout << "Real part is  " << real << endl;
  cout << "Imaginary part is  " << imag << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot provide default parameters at the function definition; you must do it at function declaration.  Instead of declaring two constructors, declare one like

```
 Complex(float a=0, float b=0);
```

Then in your definition, remove the defaults, so it becomes

```
 Complex::Complex(float a, float b)
```

Comment: You're right -- and yet, after I added the default constructor definition, it compiled for me with g++ on linux, even with the `-pedantic` flag thrown in. Weird.

Comment: That is not entirely true. Specifying the default parameters at the function definition is perfectly legal, provided that they are not specified at the declaration. You can check out [Default arguments in C++ functions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fcplr237.htm) for more information.

Comment: I am confuse in this concept. whether i can merge two constructor or not??

Comment: Consider what your default constructor would look like.  Would it set `real` and `imag` to some default value (e.g. 0)?  If so, then you can just use default arguments to `Complex(float,float)`, so that when you have something like `Complex c1;` the compiler will automatically convert it to `Complex c1(0,0);`  Also consider what happens if someone tries `Complex c1(3);`  The compiler will convert this to `Complex c1(3,0);`  If this is what you want, then you should use default values.  Does that clear up the confusion?

Answer (score 0):

Emm... seems you're missing default constructor while being using it:

```
Complex c1; // here's the error - you have no defined Complex::Complex() {} method
```